# using nuxtjs and filepond to send images to a laravel API

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt frontend using the vue-filepond adapter, users have the option to upload images with there post. This is then send to a laravel API that will handle the request.

```html
<client-only>
  <file-pond
    name="image"
    ref="pond"
    class="filepond"
    :allow-multiple="false"
    accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png"
    server="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts"
    allowRevert="false"
    :files="form.image"
  />
</client-only>
```

using mostly default filepond options,

```js
data() {
  return {
    errors: [],

    form: {
      title: '',
      content: '',
      image: [],
    }
  }
},
```

Data is uploaded to the api like so

```js
methods: {
  createPost() {
    this.$axios.$post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts', this.form)

    this.$toast.show({
      type: 'success',
      title: 'Success',
      message: 'Your post has been created'
    })
  }
}
```

Now since filePond is async the file is uploaded earlier then my form when I post it.

so in the laravel part

```php
public function store(Request $request): void
{
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $path = Storage::putFile('avatars', $request->file('image'));
    }

    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|string|max:24',
        'content' => 'required|string|max:254',
        'image' => 'nullable|image'
    ]);

    Post::create([
        'title' => $request->get('title'),
        'slug' => Str::slug($request->get('title'), '-'),
        'content' => $request->get('content'),
        'image' => $path ?? null
    ]);
}
```

The image would be stored, but if I click submit on my form to upload a title and some content the `ìmage` part in the Post::create method is always NULL.

How can I make it so that filePond is not uploaded async anymore? so that when I hit submit on my form the title , content and image are all uploaded equally

Comment: The frontend is actually building the query and sending it when everything is set. It should not send some data and some other afterwards. The `async` part of the frontend is essentially saying "I'm waiting for the backend to answer without blocking the thread" because it can take from 200ms to 5s.

Comment: Hm, how is filePond uploading it then? when I select a image it's starts uploading untill it reaches 100%. then when I want to upload my "main" form e.g. title and content, the image is not created with the Post.

Comment: Give a look to the events and methods: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/instance/events/ If I understand properly, you want to send an image and some form inputs at the same time? Watch for image's upload completed event and don't POST to the API until it's programmatically triggered by a `submit` button below your form.

Comment: Yea, uploading an image (via filepond) and some text and  content via a form is all i'm looking for

Comment: Try looking for the events and methods available as told in my previous comment.

Comment: Hey, I managed to use the `processfile` event to wait until the file is uploaded, using something like `@processfile='processFile'` on the filepond component, and in the method   ` processFile() {
      this.$axios.$post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts', this.form)
    }, `  but the form is still being uploaded piece by piece.

Comment: You need to upload it only when you click on a submit button, not when the file is loaded.

Comment: Well, I managed to hack something together using filepond events                          `const file = this.$refs.pond.getFiles()[0].file

      const data = new FormData()

      data.append('title', this.form.title)
      data.append('content', this.form.content)
      data.append('image', file)

      this.$axios.$post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts', data) `              this uploads the file at the sime time as my main form

Comment: Yep, this is the way to go! At least, this is how I did with dropzone.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to kissu and reading through filePond's docs.

```js
const file = this.$refs.pond.getFiles()[0].file

const data = new FormData()

data.append('title', this.form.title)
data.append('content', this.form.content)
data.append('image', file)

this.$axios.$post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts', data)
```

and in your backend (laravel in my case)

```php
if ($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid()) {
  $post->addMediaFromRequest('image')->toMediaCollection('image');
}
```